# How to make a button unClickable if EditText is empty?

Tags: android

I have 2 Edittext and a button I don't want the user to be able to click the button if one of the EditText is empty

and I would like to know how to let the button change color to transparent while clicking the button so it looks like you pushed the button.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this condition:

```
if(edt_text.getText().equals(""))
{
      yourbutton.setEnabled(false);
      //or
      yourbutton.setClickable(false);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mEdittext.getText()))
{
   button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

TextUtils is Class From Android Itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
how to make the button unClickable if EditText is empty
```

As other answers said :

```
if(edt_text.getText().equals(""))
{
      button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

> I have 2 Edit text and a button I don't want the user to be able to click the button if one of the EditText is empty

In this case it would be better to implement `addTextChangedListener` in order to `setEnable(false)` the button if EditText is empty, and to true if not.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(s.toString().equals("")) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

> and I would like to know how to let the button change color to transparent while clicking the button so it looks like you pushed the button

If you are using the default `Button` style, so you have nothing more to do. But If you define a `selector` drawable for your button, `setEnable()` method on the `EditText` will call the corresponding drawable of `android:state_enabled` attribute of your selector drawable (if defined).

More info on Selectors here : [StateList Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(" ") || editText.getText() == null) {

    button.setEnable(false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is short, you have to use:

```
button.setEnable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that might Help..

```
boolean check;
    txt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) 
        {
            if(!arg1)
            {
                if(!txt1.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    check=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    check=false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    txt2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) 
        {
            if(!arg1)
            {
                if(!txt2.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    check=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    check=false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if(check)
    {
        btnn.setEnabled(true);
    }
```