# Android - How to check if EditText is empty and disable Button?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button

I'm working on an Android app, most of it was with the help of tutorials and reading material, my app is somewhat basic, make some calculations and display the result to the user

**What I have**

I created a fragment guided by [this tutorial](http://haidermushtaq.com/tutorial-for-creating-android-swiping-application-using-tabbed-activity-on-android-studio/) and I just replaced the button and textview with my own EditText and Button

I have an EditText, a Button, and a TextView, these are the widgets the user see when the fragment is opened

**My goal**

I want the user to input values in the EditText and when s/he click the button the TextView displays the result of some calculations

**What I did**

I've been trying some other answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777576/how-to-make-a-button-unclickable-if-edittext-is-empty), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391809/android-check-if-edittext-is-empty), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876677/check-if-edittext-is-empty-that-only-accepts-numbers), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680106/how-to-disable-button-if-edittext-is-empty), but I don't know how to wire up the code, every time I write some pieces of code my app crashes and I don't know what else to do

Here is my code

```
public class Circle_Perimeter extends Fragment
{
    EditText edtxt;
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;

    public static Circle_Perimeter newInstance()
    {
        Circle_Perimeter fragment = new Circle_Perimeter();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Circle_Perimeter()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_circle__perimeter,container,false);

        edtxt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Question**

How and where do I write the necessary code to make the EditText send a Toast warning the user the EditText is empty? or disable the Button if the EditText is empty?

EDIT: Really?? A downvote?? Instead of downvoting... Just give a warning or something else

EDIT 2: I already said that I did follow another answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680106/how-to-disable-button-if-edittext-is-empty) and I couldn't make my code work that's why I'm here looking for an answer WITH my piece of code

Comment: where exactly is your code crashing?? can you post the `error log`?

Comment: Why not leave the button disabled and implement a onChangeListener for the editText? just curious the approach.

Comment: Unrelated to the merits of your question, please refrain from begging. I edited out the noise this caused. If your question has merit, it will not be downvoted. Begging for answers and votes will only lead to the opposite effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To notify the text changes in `EditText` you need to use `TextWatcher`. 
Please have a look at this document https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

```
public class Circle_Perimeter extends Fragment
{
    EditText edtxt;
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;

    public static Circle_Perimeter newInstance()
    {
        Circle_Perimeter fragment = new Circle_Perimeter();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Circle_Perimeter()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_circle__perimeter,container,false);

        edtxt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        //Initially set it as disabled
        btn.setEnabled(false);

        //Add textWatcher to notify the user
        edtxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //Before user enters the text
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //On user changes the text
                if(s.toString().trim().length()==0) {
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Text can not be empty..",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //After user is done entering the text

            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                //do your final job here
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NAYIR55 try this out. Hope it helps!

Comment: @downvoters, would you please be kind enough to leave the reason for down vote, that will help me improve this answer and in future

Comment: i did not down vote but i think you got that due to unnecessary code because according to his requirement no need of text watcher just find the length and validate the edit text value is empty or not when button click is enough.

Comment: @brahmyadigopula I have mentioned about TextWatcher because his requirement is "How and where do I write the necessary code to make the EditText send a Toast warning the user the EditText is empty? or disable the Button if the EditText is empty?"
So if he does the check of empty string on click of a Button and disables the Button, again how will he know that user has entered the text to enable it again ?

Comment: you can achieve that feat under button click also.i think you also how to do that..disable means make it dead  so you can achieve that through validation using length().If his requirement like button visibility then the above code is preferable.don't get angry on me mam am just an analyzer.

Comment: @brahmyadigopula Take this scenario, you have entered a text and erased it and then clicked on Button, now text length is 0 so you disable the Button and give a Toast and immediately enable the button for next click. If you again give empty text and enter and keep doing this, how is it a good practice ? 
PS I am a analyzer too, there is nothing to get angry about, I just want to know your scenario that it.

Comment: mam let's discuss in chat,gist here.

Comment: Sure, the here link has not come properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122162/discussion-between-brahmy-adigopula-and-pooja).

Comment: Using `TextChangeListener` is correct approach as this question is marked duplicate and the original questions answer also has same answer.

Comment: @pooja Do you work in agathsya technologies, B'lore?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to check that edit text is empty

```
if{edittext.getText == null){}
```

or

```
if(editText.isEmpty){}
```

Also best way is make for button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(edittext != null){
//do what u want for no empty button
}else{
//block ur button}

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `EditText` for `null` instances using the `TextUtils` API that comes bundled with `Android`

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText) {
    //Do your desired work
}else {
    //Notify user for rectification
}
```

To play around with the button, you can use either of them:

- `button.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE)`
- `button.setEnabled(false)`